# How to improve console output when running tests?

Tags: testing, jestjs

Is there a way to see better console output when running tests using Jest?

Everytime a test fails, regardless of the issue I only see the following output in the console

```
Found 1 matching tests...
FAIL  test\jestTests\xxx.spec.js (1.468s)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Furthermore, if all tests in a file pass the only output I see is the following

```
Found 1 matching tests...
PASS  test\jestTests\xxx.spec.js (1.716s)
```

I thought I might get better output if I set

```
 jasmine.VERBOSE = true;
```

but that doesn't seem to change anything. It seems strange that you don't get much more that this with the default config. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same problem. It's actually a bug, and a weird one.
Found the answer here https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/110
After I commented that line in the bin/jest file I can now see proper logs.

Comment: ah yes, I submitted that one yesterday after a day of banging my head against a wall. Sorry, I should have posted it here. Not sure how well jest has been tested within a windows environment if at all